# question_number = int(sys.argv[1]) IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

this is my first time using python, I found an error in my program that I did not understand
if **name** == '**main**':
    question_number = 1

```
question_number = int(sys.argv[1])
if (question_number > 4 or question_number < 1):
    print("Input parameters out of bound ...")
    sys.exit()

# read video file
video = cv2.VideoCapture(sys.argv[1]);
if (question_number == 1):
    skeleton_tracker1(video, "output_camshift.txt")
```

and this is the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Devi\Documents\program\DrowsyDriverDetection-master\eyedetection.py", line 128, in 
    question_number = int(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

please help and thank you before for your answer

Answer (score 1):

An IndexError is raised when you ask an iterable for an index that it doesn't have. Usually it's because that iterable doesn't have as many items as you think it does. In this example, raising IndexError on iterable[1] means that it has less than 2 items (because list indexing starts at index 0). If you are trying to get the first item in sys.argv, try sys.argv[0]. If that doesn't work either, that means that sys.argv is empty.